# How to get JSON Array value? I need to get murali printed

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Creating an Array from JSON</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const myJSON = '[{password:"murali"}]';
const myArray = JSON.parse(myJSON).password;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArray;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to get murali to get printed. This is for my React Project. I got to validate password. Hence I connected my mysql and retrive password from database and I need to validate it, In oder to validate I need to compare (database Password == input password). But as i retrive password I got the password in [{password: "murali"}] in this format and I am not able to compare with input password.

Comment: `[{password:"murali"}]` isn't valid JSON. Fix the server side code so it returns the data in a useful format. Well. Don't. Because the password comparison should be done server-side anyway.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand how the front-end code articulate with the back-end code, but to your simple question, you need to:

- name your variable correctly, `myArray` seems to be a `password` and not an array
- use `double quotes` for json keys
- access array with an `index`

Fixed, this code will print the password.

```js
const jsonString = '[{"password":"murali"}]';
const json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
const password = json[0].password;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = password;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out the issues preventing the code from running:

1. The JSON string format is incorrect.
2. The password object is the first item in an array so it must be retrieved using an index.

```
const myJSON = '[{"password":"murali"}]';       // <-- add double quotes to key
const myArray = JSON.parse(myJSON)[0].password; // <-- add array index
```